# How to pass the selected object from JSP to Java Action classes

Tags: jsp, struts2, crud

I am  able to print a list `displayList` of objects on a JSP page. Each row is an object `User`. I have a link at the end of each row for `EDIT` and `DELETE` the same object.

```xhtml
<s:iterator  value="displayList" var="eachUser" > 
             
<tr>

        <td>    <s:property  value="#eachUser.EmailId"/>  </td>
        <td>    <s:property  value="#eachUser.PasswordKey"/> </td> 
        
        
        <td> <a href="PresentRegisterScreen"> Edit  </a> </td>
        <td> <a href="DeleteUser"> Delete  </a> </td>
        

</tr>

</s:iterator>
```

The output on the screen looks as listed below

**All Records:**

```
All Registered Users - Admin View
Email Id    Password    Edit    Delete
Paul    tata    Edit    Delete
Samy    tata1$  Edit    Delete
DaLin   tiger1$ Edit    Delete
Joshua  lion1$  Edit    Delete
```

How to pass the selected object to the Action class? Or if an user clicks on edit link of `Paul`, or how to get the object in my action class.

Comment: Don't send the object you don't need it. The valuas could be changes by other users so you have to load it again from the database to make sure you are editing current values. Unless you don't lock a table to make a little change to the object you have edited the values should be the same. Edit, delete, drop, is a pattern of CRUD you can find with examples demo on Struts website or in my answer where the crud is auto generated.

Comment: When someone clicks on EDIT (or) DELETE, how do I know which row the user has selected so that I can take  that particular object / row values for Editing  / Deleting in my next action class / screen.

Answer (score 1):

> When someone clicks on EDIT (or) DELETE, how do I know which row the user has selected so that I can take that particular object / row values for Editing / Deleting in my next action class / screen.

It's easy, you need just modify links to include a parameter with the object id such as `emailId`.

```jsp
<td> <s:a action="PresentRegisterScreen"><s:param name="emailId" value="%{emailId}"/> Edit  </s:a> </td>
<td> <s:a action="DeleteUser"><s:param name="emailId" value="%{emailId}"/> Delete  </s:a> </td>
```

You have also create a property `emailId` with getter and setter to the action bean.  Now if you click a link the action will invoke and parameter is set to the action. You get a value of the property and find your object with `emailId` which you want to "EDIT (or) DELETE".

Comment: Thanks a lot Roman. It worked. It is same line with a small correction / may be typo from your side.

Comment: <td> <s:a action="DeleteUser"><s:param name="emailId" value="%{emailId}"/> Delete  </s:a> </td>

Comment: At the end , we need to close the tag <s:a action>